# KendoUI MVC How to make controls responsive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a simple page with some controls like text box, dropdown list and a grid, this is the code:

```
<div id="order">
<p>Create Order</p>
<ul id="fieldlist">
    <li>
        <label for="client">Client:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
            .Name("client")
            .Enable(false)
            .Value(@Model.ClientId.ToString() + " - " + @Model.Client)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
        )
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
            .Name("date")
            .Value(@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
        )
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("address")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("AddressId")
            .BindTo(@Model.Addresses)
            .Value(@Model.MainAddress.ToString())
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
        )
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="items">Items:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Detail)
            .Name("items")                
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(a => a.ItemId);
                columns.Bound(a => a.Name).Width(200);
                columns.Bound(a => a.Price).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" }).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(a => a.Quantity).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" }).Width(100);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolBar =>
            {
                toolBar.Save().SaveText("Send Order");
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Scrollable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .ButtonCount(5)
            )
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
            .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                .Ajax()
                .Batch(true)
                .PageSize(30)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(a => a.ItemId);
                    model.Field(a => a.Name).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(a => a.Price).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(a => a.Quantity);
                })
                .Update(update => update.Action("SendOrder", "Orders"))
        ))
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to know how can I make this page responsive on different screens or devices.
I took a look at the [telerik demos page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/) on my phone and the pages and controls adjusts to the size of the screen.

I created the project using the template Telerik C# MVC Web Application, so I have all the scripts and everything, I just don't know which classes or styles should I apply to have that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo controls are responsive itself. You need to put Kendo controls inside Bootstrap grid structure.

First of all you need to include the Bootstrap scripts and CSS in your page. 
Then you need to include the bootstrap version on Kendo CSS

- kendo.bootstrap.min
- kendo.common-bootstrap.min
- kendo.common.min

Include the following js files

- Kendo.all.min.js
- kendo.aspnetmvc.min

Now just create Bootstrap

```
<body>  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <label for="client">Client:</label>
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

              @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
                            .Name("client")
                            .Enable(false)
                            .Value(@Model.ClientId.ToString() + " - " + @Model.Client)
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
              )
        </div>

      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```